# checkboxes check automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I have a row of checkboxes:

```
<input type='checkbox' value="Maps" id="maps" >
<label for='maps'>Maps</label>
<input type='checkbox' value="wikipedia" id="wikipedia" >
<label for='maps'>Wikipedia</label>
... few more
```

I have a set of APIs that are supposed to fire within a function dependent on their respective checked box. 
As a standard, I do not have them checked. When I hit submit on user input (user selects a city name), they all select themselves.

Example function:

```
function fetchMap(city, callback){
  if ($('#maps').prop('checked',true)) {
    const query = {
        url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
        data: {
            address: city,
            key: 'noobing'
        },
        success: callback
    }
    $.ajax(query)
  }
}
```

Also, all other APIs are triggered simultaneously on user submit, whether their box is checked or not.

How do i prevent the boxes from checking themselves automatically on submit, and hence make sure that only the selected APis get AJAXed?

Thank you

Comment: You can use `is` in jQuery. `if($("#maps").is(':checked')) {`

Answer (score 3):

`$('#maps').prop('checked',true)` means that you are checking the checkbox `maps`, since there is a second parameter `true`.

If you just want to get if `maps` is checked or not, you can `$('#maps').prop('checked');`. Without the second parameter.

Like:

```
function fetchMap(city, callback){
  if ( $('#maps').prop('checked') ) { //<-- No second parameter.
    const query = {
        url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json',
        data: {
            address: city,
            key: 'noobing'
        },
        success: callback
    }
    $.ajax(query)
  }
}
```

Doc: [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)